# Diceware & Database hosting

Tags: passwords, databases

I'm currently setting up a new SQL database with DotEasy as my Hosting/Database provider.

I've heard a lot about Diceware being one of the best methods of creating a really strong password, so I figured I'd use it to create a password for my database.

DotEasy's form says that password strength must be over 55/100. So I created my password (which is 6 words long) and then went to enter it into DotEasy, the strength bar jumped to 22/100, then 30/100 as I continued to type my password, but then fell down to 0/100 when I finished typing it in. I don't understand this, I then tried a much simpler password ("holly1996") and the strength meter jumped to 68/100...

Does this mean that my diceware password would be easier to crack than I've heard, or does it mean that DotEasy have a bad password-strength rating system in place?

Comment: While your question is more specific than the one I've linked to, the same answers apply.  Strength checkers in general are conceptually flawed, and cannot truly measure the strength of a reasonably long password.

Comment: I agree with Abe's answer that the problem is with their strength meter.  You might try randomly capitalizing one or more words and throwing in a symbol between words (instead of a space) in order to game their meter into rating your password higher.

Answer (score 0):

It means that DotEasy has a bad password strength rating system.  If I recall correctly they are a pretty cut rate hosting platform.  If you are looking for something dirt cheap they are probably the way to go.  If you are looking for quality, you might look into a more expensive/respected hosting provider.

Best of luck!